# Win32 Invalid Handle Error after WriteFile failure

Tags: winapi

I have come across something strange.  I'm writing via `WriteFile` to a file opened on a UNC path to a `NAS` device.   If it runs out of space with a short write, I free up space by deleting other files, then continue writing but it is failing with windows error 6 `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.   If I do the same thing using local drives (hard drives or USB Flash Drives) it works fine.

Does anyone know why the handle becomes invalid?

Is there a type of *reset* of the handle that is needed in some cases after an error?

TIA!!

Comment: what return `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` ? use this call instead `GetLastError()`. *by deleting other files* - you random not try delete file to which you write too ?

Comment: Setting a data breakpoint on the variable that stores that handle so you can detect memory corruption is the first thing you'd do.  Next thing you'd consider is the more pragmatic solution, drag that NAS to a 4th+ story window and let it slip.  Opening the window first is optional.

Comment: No it's not deleted, I'm thinking the NAS device firmware invalidates the open handle either when the write fails or the delete occurs, I'll have to test it.